# Mysql 5.7 conectar a host remoto , situación extraña

Tags: mysql

Hace unos días se me quemo el router Mikrotik, compre uno igual y desde ese momento no puedo conectarme a mysql que esta en la nube, lo que siempre hice y funciono es:

mysql -h x.x.x.x -umiusuario -p  , ahora cuando hago esto (donde las x son el ip del host remoto) siempre me dice acceso denegado para el usuario miusuario@192.168.0.254 , donde este ip 192.168.0.254 es el de mi mikrotik. Esto es muy raro, pongo el ip del host remoto , y me da el error haciendo referencia al ip del mikrotik (que es la gateway de mi red), todo anda en mi red, solo mysql no sale a internet.

alguna idea?
Gracias, saludos

Comment: Quizá tengas que autorizar la nueva IP del cliente (supongo que cambió al cambiar el router ¿?) para que MySQL permita la conexión remota desde esa **nueva** IP.

Comment: ¿Qué obtienes de `SELECT host,isnull(password) FROM mysql.user WHERE user='miusuario';`?

Comment: El error va desde el servidor MySQL.  Su router probablemente utiliza NAT (traducción de IP.) El router sustituye su (el de router) IP por el suyo (de ud.)  Cuando el paquete llega al servidor MySQL, parece a él que la conección va del router y no de su máquina.   Es muy común en redes y tiene la ventaja que todas las conecciones de su red va a tener el mismo IP cuado llegue al servidor MySQL.